# Bluetooth switch disabled on every boot Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, xubuntu, bluetooth

I have a weird situation that has only just started occurring after I turned on write caching for my main disk. That may or may not be a coincidence, but it is when I first noticed the issue.

I used to have blueman start in the system tray with the powerstate set to off with, and the icon was greyed out, using:

`gsettings set org.blueman.plugins.powermanager auto-power-on false`

This worked great as I only occasionally use bluetooth to play music through my UE boom.  However, after enabling write caching I noticed the blueman applet loads but bluetooth is not actually enabled, so the various blueman options are all disabled.

Confirmed by: rfkill list, which only shows my wireless card.

`0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

After turning on bluetooth via the switch (Fn -> F12 F12) bluetooth shows with no hard or soft block and everything works fine.

`0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

After rebooting I have to enable via the switch again. This is not a problem since I have set bluetooth to power on automatically and when I want to use it I simply use the switch.

However, I am curious as to what really caused this and if there is a quick fix.

- Disabling write caching makes no difference,
- sudo rm -rf /var/lib/bluetooth and reinstalling blueman and bluez makes no difference.

Xubuntu 18.04 on a Toshiba L850. Bluetooth is part of the realtek wireless card, specs are as follows:

`*-network
  description: Wireless interface
  product: RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
  vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
  logical name: wlp2s0
  version: 00
  serial: 44:6d:57:52:7f:35
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723ae driverversion=4.20.17-042017-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0200000-f0203fff`

Any ideas how to set the bluetooth switch to always on when I boot?

TIA

--
Mark

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

After perusing a couple of other wireless threads, it turns out this was actually a windows 10 driver issue. That is very odd given I boot windows once a fortnight to do updates and haven't done so for a while.

Anyway, problem solved. Sorry for any bother.